# Drag & Dropping doesn't work in Nightwatch + Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, knockout.js, drag-and-drop, nightwatch.js

Using nightwatch and selenium, during a system test, I am trying to drag and drop, which is done with Knockout-draggable. It works 100% while using it manually. This is the code from the system test which is supposed to drag and drop a draggable box:

```
this.moveToElement('@box', 0, 0);
c.mouseButtonDown(0);
this.moveToElement('@box2', 0, 40);
c.mouseButtonUp(0);
```

`this` being the page (in which the xpath elements are) and `c` being the client.

But this doesn't seem to even be able to move the box under the second box (which is about 40 pixels high). Yes, I've tried different numbers and it doesn't even drag the box anywhere. Done in Firefox.

And yes, both `@box` and `@box2` are working xpaths. I have been using those for a while for a bunch of other tests.

Comment: I was trying to use this library: https://github.com/Kuniwak/html-dnd
but it seems it's not working for me, could you try this in your project

Answer (score 1):

How about put a pause between `c.mouseButtonDown(0);` and
`this.moveToElement('@box2', 0, 40);`

Answer (score 1):

Guys you have to try this and it works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE. But this works only if the element to move and the element to move to are both supporting HTML5 drag and drop feature.

Just you have to install "html-dnd" using npm, as well as this is a link -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

After installing you just have to execute this command:
`browser.execute(dragAndDrop, ['#draggable', '#droppable']);`

For example:
`browser.execute(dragAndDrop,['#elemendId1', '#elemendId2']).pause(2000);`

Hope this will work fine for your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted @Hikaryu's method and it's working for me:

```
exports.dragAndDrop = function (browser, LocatorFrom, LocatorTo) {
  browser
    .moveToElement(LocatorFrom,  10,  10)
    .mouseButtonDown(0)
    .pause(2000)
    .moveToElement(LocatorTo,  10,  10)
    .pause(2000)
    .mouseButtonUp(0);
  return browser;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a customCommand for this issue. It's working without a problem

```
module.exports.command = function (LocatorFrom, LocatorTo, callback) {

  var self = this;

  this
    .getLocation(LocatorTo, function (result) {
      let xto = result.value.x;
      let yto = result.value.y;

      this.moveToElement(LocatorFrom,  10,  10)
        .mouseButtonDown(0)
        .pause(2000)
        .moveToElement(LocatorTo,  xto,  yto)
        .pause(2000)
        .mouseButtonUp(0);
      return this;
    });



  return this;
};
```